# change timestamp datatype to rowversion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm not sure if it is necessary. I have a sql server 2008 database where all the tables have a timestamp column. is it best to change the timestamp datatype to rowversion so that it can be easily upgradeable to future sql server versions? if so,what is the best way to change all timestamp columns to rowversion without recreating the tables?

Answer (score 3):

Feel free to change your scripts to show `ROWVERSION` instead of `TIMESTAMP`, but there is no point in trying to make any changes to the table. Even in SQL Server 2012, while they have vowed long ago to eliminate the confusing name, even if you create a table like this:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo
(
  bar INT,
  rv ROWVERSION
);
```

The catalog views and everything else internal still sees that as TIMESTAMP:

```
SELECT c.name, [type] = TYPE_NAME(c.system_type_id)
  FROM sys.columns AS c
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.foo');
```

Results:

```
name type
---- ---------
foo  int
rv   timestamp
```

So I don't really think there is anything you (or anyone) can do to better prepare yourself for future versions - Microsoft is going to have a *LOT* of customers in the same boat as you, which is probably why you haven't actually seen a rapid expulsion of the type. They are probably still coming up with the plan to really eliminate it (and they are getting much better about choosing names, with the exception of `DATETIME2` IMHO).

My best advice is just to ensure that your scripts and objects all use `ROWVERSION` so that you aren't caught by surprise. This may mean manually editing scripts that you generate from Management Studio, the catalog views or even 3rd party tools.

Comment: What about using ALTER SCHEMA.. TRANSFER?  I am about to leave work, it's almost 7pm on a Friday... but curious if this is the fastest/permanent way to fix the issue.

Comment: My coworker had a freak out moment last week where he wrote a migration to drop the timestamp column and add a row version column of the same name. This is painful on a table with a billion rows

Comment: @JohnZabroski While I understand why dropping and adding a column is painful, I still don't understand what `ALTER SCHEMA ... TRANSFER` will do to help here. You're still going to have a column that all of the metadata thinks uses a data type called `timestamp`... just like your co-worker still ended up with a new column that the metadata thinks uses a data type called `timestamp`.

Comment: I just now spent some time this morning looking into this. Sorry. I was just Agitated I wasted time in my performance environment debugging a migration script rather than focusing on my actual work. Your other post here crystallized it for me: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/86531/35450